# What If I disable developer mode in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, developer-mode

I want to know what will happen if I disable developer mode in magento 1.9 by setting in `index.php` file

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}
```

to

```
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(false);
```

Will it affect my site?
Actually I want to site to be in production mode.If you have any other suggestions please share.Thanks

Comment: it is already disabled, because it is in `if condition`.if you put `die` in this if, it will not execute

Comment: Yes I found that there is not any production mode in Magento 1.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable developer mode will not any effect on magento site. It helps developer to easy to track issue nothing else.

## What is Developer mode & how we can enable in magento 1.x

Something you should do in development—but never in production—is to enable Magento's developer mode which, among other things, displays exceptions in your browser. It's useful for debugging your code.

Enable developer mode in any of the following ways:

**Developer mode**
To do this open the index.php in the root of your Magento installation and remove the comment from the line
**Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);**

**.htacess file**
Edit the .htaccess in the Magento root directory file to add SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE "true"